# Can updateInterval be set for a design document?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

In Couchbase 2.2, I have set the **updateInterval** parameter both globally (for the view update daemon) and for an individual design document. It appears that only the global setting is always taking effect. On the other hand, if I set **updateMinChanges** for a design document, it takes effect just fine.

Curiously, [the documentation example](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#couchbase-views-operation-autoupdate) does not show **updateInterval** being set for a design document:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/myddoc",
   "views": {
      "view1": {
          "map": "function(doc, meta) { if (doc.value) { emit(doc.value, meta.id);} }"
      }
   },
   "options": {
       "updateMinChanges": 1000,
       "replicaUpdateMinChanges": 20000
   }
}
```

Can updateInterval be set for a design document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not currently possible to set an updateInterval at the design document level.  A feature request has been added to provide this function @ **https://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-11594**